# Desktop sharing where multiple users can share and viewer can view all desktops at once

Tags: screen-sharing

I was looking for the following feature:

I am interacting with my clients (let's say they are 10 in number). I would like them to share their screens and I would like to view those from my desktop.

Is this possible? If yes, can you please let me know the software that supports this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention budget, so I'll suggest WebEX.  There's multiple flavors, at multiple price-levels, but for ease of use/robustness/feature set, it's pretty tough to beat.

Some other options that may work:

- [VNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/)/TightVNC (open source/free, but requires firewall ports to be open)
- [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/) (lots of options here; no firewall changes required)
- [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) (no firewall changes required)

Comment: I can speak from experience that TeamViewer works great. TV is free for personal use, but will limit you by logging your session off and requiring a wait time if you try to connect to domain computers if you do not have a commercial license, which start at about $700. With that license, you can have an infinite number of client computers you connect to. That is a big advantage in that it does not cost more as you add clients. I use it and have such a license.

Comment: One more thing: There are also versions, which run, rather than have to be installed, so even if the users are locked down, you can still help them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But using TeamViewer will I able to view multiple shared screens(users desktops) at once i.e., 5 windows showing 5 shared screens.

Comment: Doubtful, unless there's a conferencing flavor of it. That's where you'd typically find that feature set, under "web conferencing".

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the helpful suggestions. From what I came across, I couldn't find any solution where I can see multiple sharers at once. 1-many (one sharer - many viewers) is common, but many-1 or many-many (many sharers-many viewers) doesn't seem to be around.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Live meeting will do this as well as WebEx and others as mentioned.  If teh cinet sue Windows, they can also send a Remote Assitance request that would provide access.  However, it requires ports to be opened.  It is free and in Windows XP and later.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does Live Meeting allow me to see multiple shared screens at once.?